# How to delete rows from a table when we're joining and return data?

Tags: postgresql, join, select, delete

I have two queries:

**The first one is as below:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM batch bp 
  INNER JOIN sender_log sl ON sl.id=bp.log_id 
    AND bp.protocol='someprotocol'
```

**The second query is used to delete rows:**

```
delete from batch where protocol='someprotocol'
```

I know that in postgres we have **RETURNING *** to return deleted rows. What I want to achieve is to delete rows and return them in one query. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Very simple indeed, but you *do* need to include the other `WHERE` clause as well:

```
DELETE FROM batch bp
USING  sender_log sl
WHERE  bp.log_id = sl.id
AND    bp.protocol = 'someprotocol'
RETURNING bp.*, sl.*;
```

And to actually return what your question outlines, you need to include both tables in the [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html).

Answer (score 3):

Very simple indeed:

```
DELETE FROM batch bp
USING sender_log sl
WHERE bp.log_id = sl.id
RETURNING sl.packet
```

;-)

Comment: What does `RETUNRNING sl.packet` do?

Comment: @Mihai: I added a link to my answer, the manual explains.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, your answer fulfills what I've asked. thanks. +1